# Fatal error in magento v 1.5

Tags: php, magento, mage

I have installed the follow up email extension in my magento V1.5.. After installed admin panel which is display like this:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Followupemail_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /home/shared/nftn/app/Mage.php on line 520

```
$registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
        self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
}
```

I don't know how to remove that error. Can any one tell me????

Comment: Have you logged out & logged in to your backend again? And have you cleared all caches (+ flush cache storage). Most of the times that will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error is caused by the Followup Email extension. If you remove all it's files, the error has to be gone.